# RegEx string to find two strings and delete the rest of the text in the file

Tags: regex, find, notepad++

I need to do a find and delete the rest in a text file with notepad+++
i want tu use RegeX to find variations on thban..... the variable always has max 5 chars behind it(see dots).
with my search string it hit the last line but the whole line. I just want the word preserved.
When this works i also want keep the words containing C3.....
The rest of a tekst file can be delete.
It should also be caps insensitive

```
(?!thban\w+).*\r?\n?
```

\

```
THBANES900 and C3950 bla bla
THBAN
..THBANES901.. C3850 bla bla
THBANMP900
**..thbanes900..**
```

This should result in

```
THBANES900 C3950
THBAN
THBANES901 C3850
THBANMP900
thbanes900
```

Comment: What do you mean with “it always has max 5 chars behind it” your example doesn't show that. Do you mean “after”? Then why does the line with `THBAN` alone stay the same?

Comment: appolgies i'll ammend but indeed i mean after the fixed string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe just capture those words of interest instead of replacing everything else? In Notepad++ search for pattern:

```
^.*\b(thban\S{0,5})(?:.*(\sC3\w+))?.*$|.+
```

See the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pt99hM/5)

- `^` - Start string ancor.
- `.*\b` - Any character other than newline zero or more times upto a word-boundary.
- `(`- Open 1st capture group.

  - `thban\S{0,5}` - Match "thban" and zero or 5 non-whitespace chars.
  - `)` - Close 1st capture group.
- `(?:` - Open non-capturing group.

  - `.*` - Any character other than newline zero or more times.
  - `(` - Open 2nd capture group.

    - `\sC3\w+` - A whitespace character, match "C3" and one ore more word characters.
    - `)` - Close 2nd capture group.
  - `)?` - Close non-capturing group and make it optional.
- `.*` - Any character other than newline zero or more times.
- `$` - End string ancor.
- `|` - Alternation (OR).
- `.+` - Any character other than newline once or more.

Replace with:

```
$1$2
```

---

After this, you may end up with empty line you can switly remove using the build-in option. I'm unaware of the english terms so I made a GIF to show you where to find these buttons:

[image]

I'm not sure what the english checkbutton is for ignore case. But make sure that is not ticked.

Comment: I just saw your answer when posting mine. You got my vote.

Comment: Just a remarck, I'd insert word boundaries before `thban` and `C3`

Answer (score 1):

You may use

**Find What**:      `(?|\b(thban\S{0,5})|\s(C3\w+))|(?s:.)`
**Replace With**: `(?1$1\n:)`

**Screenshot & settings**

[image]

**Details**

- `(?|` - start of a branch reset group:

  - `\b(thban\S{0,5})` - Group 1: a word boundary, then `thban` and any 0 to 5 non-whitespace chars
  - `|` - or
  - `\s(C3\w+)` - a whitespace char, and then Group 1: `C3` and one or more word chars
- `)` - end of the branch reset group
- `|` - or
- `(?s:.)` - any one char (including line break chars)

The replacement is

- `(?1` - if Group 1 matched,

  - `$1\n` - Group 1 value with a newline
  - `:` - else, replace with empty string
- `)` - end  of the conditional replacement pattern