# RegEx string to find two strings and delete the rest of the text in the file including lines that don't contain the strings

Tags: regex, find, notepad

I have the following challenge which was solved by JvdV (thanks) but i didn't make it clear that there are also lines with only none related text. "bla bla" in the example below.

Details of the first part of my question

[RegEx string to find two strings and delete the rest of the text in the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62451653/regex-string-to-find-two-strings-and-delete-the-rest-of-the-text-in-the-file)

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pt99hM/4)

```
^.*\b(thban\S{0,5})(?:.*\s(C3\w+))?.*$
```

How do i also match the line with only bla bla

```
THBANES900 and C3950 bla bla
THBAN
..THBANES901.. C3850 bla bla
THBANMP900
**..thbanes900..**
bla bla
```

This should result in

```
THBANES900 C3950
THBAN
THBANES901 C3850
THBANMP900
thbanes900
```

Comment: So you want either 1 or 2 groups or remove the whole line? Try using an alternation `^.*\b(thban\S{0,5})(?:.*\s(C3\w+))?.*$|.+` https://regex101.com/r/jq1oP3/1

Comment: Use `(?|\b(thban\S{0,5})|\s(C3\w+))|(?s:.)` and replace with `(?1$1\n:)`. Actually, if the question you asked was not properly answered, do not ask a new question. It is a duplicate of what you asked before.

Comment: @JvdV "and delete the rest of the text in the file" was not dealt with in your answer.

Comment: To add `\s` from outside to inside group 2 and also use of `|` after last question-mark gives me your intended Output..... like this ⇉ `^.*\b(thban\S{0,5})(?:.*(\sC3\w+))?|.*` and replace it with ... `$1$2`

Comment: But seems a bit exhaustic regex, may cause engine exhausted